# Updating a composable state from another composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list of items along with a search bar and I am filtering the list of items based on the text in the search bar.

The problem I am running into is after the list is filtered correctly I want the scroll the list of items to the top again.

I know about state hoisting but if I hoist the lazylist state up to the level of the search bar basically all my composable will be recomposing unnecessarily.

Here is my root composable

```
@Composable
fun App(viewModel: ViewModel, window: ComposeWindow) {
    val loading = viewModel.loadingStateFlow.collectAsState()

    Theme {
        Column{
            Menu(viewModel)
            Divider()

            if (loading.value) {
                LinearProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
            }

            SearchBar(viewModel){
                //callback when query changes
            }
            FilterChips(viewModel, Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally))
            MessagesList(viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

My list composable

```
@Composable
fun MessagesList(viewModel: LogViewModel) {
    val messages = viewModel.messagesStateFlow.collectAsState()
    val state = rememberLazyListState()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){

        LazyColumn(state = state) {
            items(messages.value.size) { index ->
                val message = messages.value[index]
                MessageRow(message.message)
            }
        }

        VerticalScrollbar(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd).fillMaxHeight().padding(end = 4.dp),
            adapter = rememberScrollbarAdapter(state),
            style = ScrollbarStyle(
                minimalHeight = 32.dp,
                thickness = 8.dp,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                hoverDurationMillis = 300,
                unhoverColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary.copy(alpha = 0.50f),
                hoverColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
            )
        )
    }
}
```

So I know I could move `rememberLazyListState()` from the MessagesList composable up into my root composable then update the state in the query change callback but thats going to recompose all my composables and that hardly seems efficient and/or necessary.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, when you apply a filter, this variable will be changed because the Flow now returns filtered data:

```
val messages = viewModel.messagesStateFlow.collectAsState()
```

If you now want to trigger some code whenever the `messages` value changes, you can use a [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect):

```
val state = rememberLazyListState()

LaunchedEffect(messages) {
    state.scrollToItem(0)
    // or for animated scrolling to the top:
    // state.animateScrollToItem(0)
}
```

This will trigger the code within the `LaunchedEffect` whenever `messages` changes.

---

As a small side note, you use a fairly atypical structure in your App. I don't know if that could lead to problems, but a typical structure would look like this:

```
setContent {
    Theme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
            App(/* ... */)
        }
    }
}
```